# Does Btrfs provide some sort of way to identify a file even if the path is changed, like an invariant ID?

Tags: btrfs

Does Btrfs provide any method to identify a file other than its path? I mean, if there was a file `/my/directory/a.txt` and if someone or something moved it to `/my/other/directory/b.txt`, it is still the same file, but since the path has been changed, I would have no way to know if the "b.txt" was "a.txt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [inode numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) (see `ls -i`, `stat`), like in many (all?) other *nix filesystems. In Btrfs they are stable (they don't change after reboot, they don't change if you mount in another machine), but unique only inside a subvolume (not inside an entire filesystem<sup>1</sup>); and they can be reused.

Two paths reporting the same inode number at the same time inside the same subvolume lead to the same file; this is [how hardlinks work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50188/108618). But in general you cannot be sure if today's inode number *N* is the same file as yesterday's *N*.

Keeping a hardlink in a directory nobody can access may be a workaround; because as long as the hardlink exists, its inode number cannot be reused inside the same subvolume. Then you can [list all files with the same inode number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73538/108618) on demand.

Still there are scenarios when you cannot track the file because in the new location it's formally a different file. These include:

- When the original is "moved" by being copied+deleted (regardless if CoW-copy or not).
- When the original is moved to another subvolume.
- When the original is moved to another filesystem (this is [copy+delete really](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48090/108618)).

---

<sup>1</sup> Note two different subvolumes mean two different device numbers, *even* if they are accessible under a single mountpoint (where their (grand-…-)parent subvolume is mounted). This is how Btrfs works.

Comment: "inode ... unique only inside a subvolume (not inside an entire filesystem);" I think that needs more details. Do you mean that you can mount a single btrfs file system on some mount point (eg. on `/mnt/foo`) and have two different files with same device id and inode, if they're on separate "subvolumes"?

Comment: @user414777 No. Two different subvolumes mean two different device numbers, *even* if they are under a single mountpoint.

Comment: Interesting. Btrfs apparently allocates device numbers dynamically for its subvolumes, including for the top one. The device number of a file does not correspond to the actual block device in any way, and may be different, depending on the order in which btrfs fileystems were mounted.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you should create a hard link to that file eg. with

```
ln -L /path/to/a.txt /unique/path/in/the/same/fs
```

If that succeeds, you will still be able to access the file even if it was renamed or removed.

I'm not aware of any way to create a "weak" hard link (a hard link which would automatically removed when all the other hard links to the file are removed).

Comment: No, I cannot use link, because this question was mainly about my reorganising the file/directory structure. I would like to know which files are moved to where to copy only new files, not moved/renamed files when doing back-up (not using existing back-up software, because of my complex situation).

Comment: @DamnVegetables sounds like using the [birth/creation time](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html) would be a better option. Not inode numbers, which can be reused. But it's really not clear what your trying to do -- reinvent `rsync`?

Comment: I did not get notification for this comment. Weird. I'm not sure how rsync works but, I don't have a large back up drive but small hard drives. And I don't want to connect all of them each time I back up. So, basically, I want to copy only changed files to one last small drive. And I want to keep track of which files are where, so that in case the big disk dies, I could reconstruct it from the backed-up files spread on the multiple small disks. I thought that kind of requirement is complicated, so I thought of writing my own programme for that.